# IOS Simulator 5 webview error : CALayerInvalidGeometry

Tags: uiwebview, calayer, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

I have webview inside scroll view, and that scrollview is also inside another scroll (page control).

my question is i get this following error

```
This is the error:
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1583052 0x196cd0a 0x152ba78 0x152b9e9 0x4c9de99 0x4c94205 0x233ebb3 0x76598e 0x96d495       0x764a5e 0x1584e1a 0x14ee821 0x622349 0x60ead4 0x615bee 0x6194e6 0x88de39 0x88d143 0x88e3cf 0x890a31 0x89098c 0x8893e7 0x5f1812 0x5f1ba2 0x5d8384 0x5cbaa9 0x20b1fa9 0x15571c5 0x14bc022 0x14ba90a 0x14b9db4 0x14b9ccb 0x20b0879 0x20b093e 0x5c9a9b 0x302d 0x2895)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

This is my code that i think the problem (because if i comment blogThumbnailWebview loadRequest:request] it is working fine. no error.

```
- (void) setVideoAsThumbnail:(NSString *)videoThumbnailLink
{    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoThumbnailLink]];
blogThumbnailWebView .scalesPageToFit = NO;
[blogThumbnailWebView loadRequest:request];
blogThumbnailWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = NO;
 }
```

However the error is only in Simulator 5, if i use simulator 4.3 there is no error.

How can i solve that?

FYI: Im using ARC, and Xcode 4.2 SDK 5

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize the webview, make sure you don't use the plain *init* method, but rather one like *initWithFrame*. By using the plain *init*, sometimes there is no frame allocated when the component is being used, thus throwing the CALayerInvalidGeometry error.